# How to use nested arrays with a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

My goal for this is to be able to access properties of a nested array in a for loop, for example given the array.

```
[[1 , "one"],
[0.2 , "two"],
[0.3 , "three"]]
```

I'd like to be able to access index 0 over a loop.

My current way of doing this is:

```
function printArray() {
  for (var i = arguments.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    print(arguments[i][0]);
  }
}
```

How ever this produces this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

When I expected

```
0.3
0.2
1
```

What is the correct way of looping over a nested array?

Comment: Try `for (var i = arguments.length-1;...`. From the [MDN Array page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array): "JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1."

Comment: `for (const arg of [...arguments]){ for (const nestedArg of arg) { console.log(nestedArg);}}`.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Your current code uses a variable `arguments` which is not declared anywhere. I can try to guess how the variable is declared, but I doubt that I will recreate the error you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This is the minimal reproducible example. [The arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is a part of every JavaScript function.

Comment: @TasLong Yes, I got hung up on a detail that I am unfamiliar with in the language. Thanks for the link that explains `arguments`. I suggest that you avoid using this and explicitly name the parameters to your function instead. In addition, when I copy and paste your code, it does not reproduce the error you are asking about because you are missing how you call the function. I can try to guess how you do this, but it would be better if you include the function call in your code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to loop through an array.

Which one is the best?

It depends on what it's used for, and subjectivity.

Here's a few of them.

```js
let arr = [[1 , "one"], [0.2 , "two"], [0.3 , "three"]];

// forEach loop
console.log('forEach loop');
arr.forEach((x, idx) => {
    console.log(x[0]);
});

//for of loop
console.log('for-of loop');
for (elem of arr){
   console.log(elem[0]);
}

//for in loop
console.log('for-in loop');
for (idx in arr){
    console.log(arr[idx][0]);
}

// old-school for loop
console.log('for loop');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    console.log(arr[i][0]); 
}

// while loop
console.log('while loop');
let i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
    console.log(arr[i][0]);
    i++;
}

// do while loop
console.log('do while loop');
let j = 0;
do {
    console.log(arr[j][0]);
    j++;
} while (j < arr.length);
```

But about your function.
1) it's better to pass the array as a variable.
2) the last index of an array is it's length - 1

So if you want something that even works in older browsers.

To loop in ascending order of the index:

```
function printArray(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    print(arr[i][0]);
  }
}
```

To loop in descending order of the index:

```
function printArray(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    print(arr[i][0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP appears to want to iterate over the array in reverse order. Can you show how to do that correctly?

Comment: His example does do it in reverse, but besides that code, that intention isn't made clear in the question.  But ok, I'll include a reverse.

Comment: I agree, the original question requires a few guesses to understand what the OP is trying to do. I see that the desired output is listed in the reverse order of the input, so I think that's the closest we'll get to explicit requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for/of` for iterables so you don't have to even worry about index dereferencing.

```js
function printArray () {
  for (const arg of [...arguments]) {
    for (const nestedArg of arg) {
      console.log(nestedArg);
    }
  }
};

printArray([
  [1, "one"],
  [0.2, "two"],
  [0.3, "three"]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration is i=3, that's past the array boundaries if used as index

```js
let args = [
  [1, "one"],
  [0.2, "two"],
  [0.3, "three"]
];

for (let i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(args[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is array of arguments pass to the function, in your case you should point to the first element of the argument array  like this:

```js
let data = [[1 , "one"],
    [0.2 , "two"],
    [0.3 , "three"]];


function printArray() {
  for (var i = arguments[0].length -1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(arguments[0][i][0]);
  }
}

printArray(data);
```

The error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

come form arguments.length, that will cause index out of bound array error

Comment: `arguments[0][i][0]` This gets the first letter of each string. I don't think that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, didn't get your point, in my snippet its working well, maybe I didn't get the question.

Comment: Yah, I see that and I don't understand how. Where is `arguments` declared?

Comment: OIC...`arguments` is a magic JavaScript variable that stores the arguments to the functions, I guess. I mixed that up with `data`.

Comment: Note that this is making an assumption about how the function is called. The OP might be calling `printArray(...data)` instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, no worries.

Comment: yes, but I was think about how he might be calling the function since he used `arguments` I think @zero298, @LukStorms is the best answers for this question.